# Python Fastest way to get the strings from a large list of strings that contains a substing(address auto complete)

Tags: python, arrays

I am building a GUI that has an auto complete field for addresses.

The address database has 400000 entries and is pulled into a dataframe in memory when the program loads.

I am using tkinker and have an auto complete entry field that when the user starts to type it shows a list of possible matching addresses.

The problem is, it is very slow when they type....

When the data loads I combine the addresses into a string IE "2 Roderick Lane Knoxville"

Then the user can start typing "Roder" for example and this address would be shown among others in a dropdown to auto complete.

Long story short I need a faster way to parse a large list of strings and return any strings that match a substring.  I have tried a couple of different ways but neither are fast enough:

Using a dataframe:(self.addresses['combined'] is strings)

```
df = self.addresses[self.addresses['combined'].str.contains(theSubString)]
return list(set(df['combined'].tolist()))
```

and using a list:(self.addresses is a list of strings)

```
return [w for w in self.addresses if theSubString in w]
```

Comment: The performance is going to be dominated by the time it takes to compare all the strings. Unless you can come up with an indexing scheme, the iteration method is not going to make much difference.

Comment: If you allowed only matches at the start of a word (Roder, Lan, Knox, ...) a prefix tree would help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I assume you don't want to show all results at once. See my answer to show the first n results. This can make your search much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the `filter` function?

```
list(filter(lambda x: theSubString in x, self.addresses))
```

I assume that you don't want to show all results, but perhaps only the first n results that contain the substring. This could make your code much faster.
You can use `itertools.islice` to get the first results from `filter`.

```
n = 10
list(islice(filter(lambda x: theSubString in x, addresses), n))
```

Comment: The time is dominated by the string comparisons, not the iteration function.

Comment: Than you very much. The filter did not help the speed but the islice was the key. I was pulling way to many records even though I was only showing 10. Thanks for the help